# One of my XAML forms looks different in design as opposed to debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

One of the XAML forms in my project looks how I want it to when in design, but when I debug the elements of the form are different sizes and in different places. How do I fix this?

[image]

I apologize if my XAML code is unhelpful.  I am unfamiliar with XAML and don't really know what to include. I can add any extra code if necessary.

I have tried deleting and re-adding the elements that are in different positions when debugging from the form.

The textblock is misaligned in the debug form and the listbox is larger than it should be.

**Xaml**

```
</ContentDialog>
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" Margin="766,793,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="463" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FF1B0303" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarBorderThemeBrush}"/>
<ListBox Margin="1617,192,21,348"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the picture you have attached I can only assume that for text box you have different margin specified than for rectangle. That is quite easy to test.

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" Margin="766,793,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="463" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FF1B0303" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarBorderThemeBrush}"/>
```

There's 2 important clues here -

> Margin="766,793,0,0" //relative position in parent element
>
> Width="463" Height="195" // size of rectangle

compare these values with textblocks you're referencing and hopefully you will find the issue.

Note : full screen app will have different window size than design, so the relative positions will also change. Try change window width/height in design (to your full screen res) and that should show the same view as running app.

You can try to position both of them within same parent (e.g. grid). I've tested with this UWP xaml and it seems to be doing the trick :

```
<Grid Margin="766,793,0,0" Width="463" Height="195">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="#FF1B0303" Fill="{ThemeResource AppBarBorderThemeBrush}"/>
            <ListBox>
                <TextBlock Text="asda"/>
                <TextBlock Text="asda"/>
                <TextBlock Text="asda"/>
                <TextBlock Text="asda"/>
                <TextBlock Text="asda"/>
            </ListBox>
 </Grid>
```

Esentially parent element grid will set size and location, and child elements will inherit these properties.

Comment: That makes it so that the text is aligned with the rectangle, but both the rectangle and the textblock are aligned left on the form, and the listbox is still to big. Any idea what I should do there?

Answer (score 0):

> One of my XAML forms looks different in design as opposed to debug

The problem is that you have used `Margin` to make absolute layout. When the window size changed the control will fixed on the `Margin="766,793,0,0"`. The better way is make adaptive layout. For example.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Fill="Aqua" Height="200"/>
    <ListView Height="200" Grid.Column="1" Background="Beige">
        <x:String>Test Value</x:String>
        <x:String>Test Value</x:String>
        <x:String>Test Value</x:String>
        <x:String>Test Value</x:String>
    </ListView>
    <Image Stretch="Fill" Height="200" Grid.Column="2" Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" />
</Grid>
```

For more detail please refer l[ayouts with XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/layouts-with-xaml).